# ComponentDidMount infinite loop

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

first of all I'd like to say I have read about the subject and I still can't understand what's happening, so sorry in advance if it's a duplicate. component that fetches data from a server on componentDidMount, but somehow it enters an infinite loop. I am using react router & redux saga and the parent of said component is also connected to the redux store (I think this is the problem).

App.js render method:

```
render() {
console.log(this.props.isAuthenticated);
let routes = (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Redirect to="/" />
  </Switch>
);

if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
  routes = (
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/logout' component={Logout} />
      <Route path='/data/people' component={People} />
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Redirect to="/" />
    </Switch>
  )
}

return (
  <div>
    <Layout>
      {routes}
    </Layout>
  </div>
);
}
```

Call to fetch data (Called in People.js):

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchPeople()
}
```

App.js redux connection:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.login.token !== null,
    username: state.login.username
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    autoLogin: () => dispatch(actions.checkLoginState())
  }
};`
```

People.js redux connection:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    people: state.data.people,
    loading: state.data.loading
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchPeople: () => dispatch(actions.fetchPeople())
  };
};
```

actions.fetchPeople calls this saga:

```
export function* fetchPeopleSaga () {
  try {
    yield put(actions.fetchPeopleStart());
    const people = yield axios.get('/data/people');
    yield put(actions.fetchPeopleSuccess(people));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(actions.fetchPeopleFail(error));
  }
};
```

And here's the relevant reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  people: null,
  error: null,
  loading: false
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.FETCH_PEOPLE_START:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      }
    case actionTypes.FETCH_PEOPLE_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        people: action.people,
        loading: false
      }
    case actionTypes.FETCH_PEOPLE_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        people: null,
        error: action.error,
        loading: false
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
};
```

As you can see they aren't even accessing the same props, so I don't understand why it enters infinite rendering.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you post your `actions.fetchPeople()` method please?...

Comment: Posted the relevant saga and reducer :)

Comment: `console.log(this.props.isAuthenticated)` in render of App.js - what happens?

Comment: @Dominic it prints false and then true and then my browser terminates the process

Comment: @SagiRika Just twice? Interesting, is this all you have in lifecycle methods in People.js or are you also using componentDidUpdate?

Comment: @Dominic This is the only one.

Comment: If CDM is being triggered in a loop then something is unmounting and remounting the component in a loop. It's hard to say what from this code, it's strange that your App.js render only happens twice and I'm not convinced the issue is in the code you have so far posted

Comment: @Dominic Can I help by posting other parts of the code? I am not using People in any other component.

Comment: @SagiRika please post the whole render method of App.js, any addional lifecycle methods in App.js or People.js, and any extra HOCs wrapping People.js if there are any more. Ensure you're not calling setState in a way that can loop . Also check Redux DevToools to see what actions are going in a loop, check the URL isn't changing in a loop. Try reducing code down to necessary parts too.

Comment: @Dominic I added the entire render method, there are no additional lifecycle methods on both of the components and the only hoc on People is redux's connect. I am not calling setState in a loop and the action thats getting called in a loop is FETCH_PEOPLE.

Comment: Is Layout doing anything with state? Listening for state changes etc? If not then this is a strange one, don't think I can help without a runnable example!

Comment: @Dominic I fixed the problem, it was in actionTypes, some wrong syntax there. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another state `loaded` and set it to true in case of either `FETCH_PEOPLE_SUCCESS` or `FETCH_PEOPLE_FAIL`. Then, add a check for both loaded and loading before you fetch people data, something like:

```
if (!loaded && !loading) {
    this.props.fetchPeople()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ComponentDidMount get called once unless you redirect to that page again.
Please check, you must be getting redirecting on that page/component again and again.